# Discrete set is enumerable

Tags: real-analysis

If a set is discrete, then it's countable.
In another words, every non-countable set has at least one accumulation point.

My idea to proof this was:

$\,$

Let $X$ be a discrete set. Then, it has no accumulation points (by definition of discrete set).

We define $B_a[a;\varepsilon]$ as the ball of center $a \in X$ and radius $\varepsilon > 0$, and $X_a = X \, \cap \, B_a$.

If $X_a$ had infinite points, then it would have an accumulation point (by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem), so it has to be a finite set.

So, as:

$$X=\bigcup_{a \in X}X_a$$

We would have an union of finite sets, and so, $X$ would be enumerable.

$\,$

But my teacher said that the "$a \in X$" part of the union of the $X_a$'s was a problem, because if we index in that way, we lose control of the enumerability, and I couldn't think another way to index that.

Any tips? Or another way to proof this?

Comment: When you say "a set", do you mean "a subset of $\Bbb R$"? Or something else?

Comment: Subset from $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: No mention of that in the question.....

Comment: HINT: Use the fact that $\Bbb R^n$ has a countable base (e.g., the set of open balls with rational radii and centres in $\Bbb Q^n$).

Comment: Angina, it's because the question in the book is written exactly in that way I wrote, but the book is about Real Analysis and I should've written it. Sorry.